# using my own data Timemanager

Tags: qgis, timemanager

I created a small dataset in google sheets. The columns are date, latitude and longitude, and size. I added the csv layer to my map, and then added the layer to timemanager plugin. for some reason, when i turn timemanager on, the layer no longer appears. any ideas why this might be happening?

I am using qgis 2.12.3 lyon.

Answer (score 0):

I would store the data in a distinct shapefile prior trying to create some visuals with timemanager. 
Furthermore a screenshot with your current settings in time manager and the attribut table would be a great help!